# Add Multiple Elements to ListModel using Combo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I want to add multiple elements to `JList` using `JComboBox`. When user select an item from the `JComboBox`, it should add to `JList`. If the item already exists in the List message should pop up to notify that. How do I do this?

```
private void cmbBagSizeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    lstBagSize.setModel(listModel);

    if ((evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)) {
          if (listModel.getSize() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listModel.getSize(); i++) {
                      listModel.addElement(cmbBagSize.getModel().getSelectedItem());
                      break;
                }
          } else {
                listModel.addElement(cmbBagSize.getModel().getSelectedItem());
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to above issue. I used method called contains to check where any duplicates exists.

```
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

        if (listModel.contains(this.cmbBagSize.getSelectedItem())) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate");

        } else {

              listModel.addElement(this.cmbBagSize.getSelectedItem());
              this.lstBagSize.setModel(listModel);
        }
```